# How do i make sure that my mail($to,$subject,$msg); delivers the mail

Tags: php

My computer has got apache installed(localhost), so i made a signup option, and there is an email option to which i send a mail for activation of account. I have an internet connection, now if in the PHP script, i write
    mail($to,$subject,$msg);
will this code deliver the mail to the desired recepient because it is not sending it.

Comment: I'm flagging this for migration to serverfault.com because the problem is to do with your server setup.

Comment: I'm not sure where this should go. It could be a coding problem, it could be a server problem, or it could be a spam filter problem.

Comment: Use dedicated mail-sending classes like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), for example. Configure it to use SMTP directly, so you can send emails just like if you would have send it via Outlook/Thunderbird/ or any other mail client without having mail server on your PC.

Comment: @John Conde - ... or even an [ISP problem](http://www.zdnet.com/news/comcast-takes-hard-line-against-spam/136518)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to be 100% sure an email was received by a recipient.

The `mail()` function returns a value depending on whether there was a problem sending the email or not. You would do that like this:

```
$successful = mail($to,$subject,$msg);
if (!$successful)
{
    // The email was not sent
}
```

If the value of `$successful` is `false` then the server had an issue sending the email. So add that to your code and see what happens. If `$successful` is  `true` then the server is sending the email ok and your problem may lie with spam filters that are receiving the email and deleting it. You can learn more about how to prevent that in [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam).

Comment: but all i would need is a web server on my computer and an internet access right? for my mails to be delivered?

Comment: And a mail server like [Mercury Mail](http://www.pmail.com/). If you don't have that then you know why it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah. $successful is false. howcome? i dont know.

Comment: supplemental information regarding deliverability.. the mail() function has no way to guarantee that your email will reach its destination. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include headers:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
```

Without headers you'll probably get marked as SPAM by the recipient mail server.